# MATLAB: which language interface to use when calling external library functions offered with various interfaces?

Tags: matlab

Still very new to MATLAB and to programming in general, I got stuck in understanding how to best make profit from what is documented in the official MATLAB documentation in the chapter Calling External Functions. I am by now not capable to judge which of the many offered pathways might be the most effective one to go for, in terms of how easy a pathway can be learned by a beginner and which one could on the long term most easy and clear in the MATLAB code be applied over and over again.

To put it in a very practical question: as, for instance, the third party image processing function libraries ITK or OpenCV provide Java, C++, C and Python interfaces, and MATLAB has functionality to address such interfaces, which interface should a beginner in programming chose? Is one of them usable in a clearer laid out design and thus easier to get warm with and quicker to learn to apply?

I am afraid to now hear from everybody something like "well, it depends what you want to do", and my answer could only be "don´t know yet, I am learning programming and prefer to first gain some general success by going for the cleaner designed and easier to understand approach, and thus would like to get a recommendation where to start".

Please let me add this to my question and concerns: Highly respected Yair Altman states on his internet page "undocumentedmatlab.com" in the commercial for his "Undocumented Secrets of Matlab-Java Programming" book, that the Matlab programming environment would rely on Java for numerous tasks, including networking, data-processing algorithms and graphical user-interface (GUI). I derive from this statement that learning to specially connect MATLAB to JAVA will have significant advantages, THE MATHWORKS itself seem to have decided to take advantage of such connection when implementing MATLAB.

But I can also see, that THE MATHWORKS by providing for MATLAB the MEX functionality seems to lean towards a tight C/C++ incorporation, providing also MEX besides the other possibilities to call external C functions.

For me as a beginner it is now confusing to uncover which route of connectivity to external languages could be taken as the "standard" or "first to be recommended" one. Do any of you experienced programmers would have some arguments for me which route to first focus on? It is a long journey to learn programming, and I would not like to waste time on poorly recommended pathways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Start with you can look for Interfacing MATLAB and Java (It is easiest way to learn)

Afterwards, Go for Interfacing MATLAB and C++

```
1. Create Classes and Gateway in C++ for MATLAB and create executable mex file
2. Create MATLAB function and Wrap in C++  (Shared C/C++ library approach)
```

Afterwards, Go for creating Excel Addins and Invoke those addins in Excel Sheets

Meanwhile you can look for dll referencing in C#.net application /VB.net application

Comment: Thanks for this roadmap for safely growing in programming with MATLAB. As performance issues, which would ask for the C/C++ MEX-file pathway, is at the moment not my main concern (see comments exchanged with @carlosdc), but the easier way to gain some connectivity to external libraries is, and your recommendation in this regard equals to the MATLAB support answer I got, I will try out the JAVA path first, for my general needs. Nevertheless, with the availability of the openCV MATLAB bindings, the second step to also learn the MEX and C/C++ interfacing will for sure (have to) follow soon, then.

Answer (score 3):

This question sounds like: "I am still learning how to drive, still not a very experienced driver. Please give me your tips about how to change a flat tire, what is the best tire to get a flat tire on, passenger side rear? what are the best places to get a flat tire, is it the mall or my office parking lot or the middle of the street."

Let me give you some tips:

- Changing a tire will not make you a more knowledgeable driver. You will learn very few things from doing it and it is a frustrating experience and it is not worth your time right now. Learn how to drive.

**Explanation:** Making MATLAB call Java/C++/C or whatever other language will not make you a better MATLAB programmer, and frankly is of secondary importance. Until the first sentence of your question isn't "I'm still new to MATLAB and programming in general" you're wasting your time. Like changing a flat tire, connecting MATLAB to other languages is not something cool, or interesting, in fact it is the opposite: it is frustrating, error prone and boring.

- The day will come when you will have a flat tire. That day the location where you get it and which tire it is will become secondary. You will need to learn how to change it and you will. Trust me you will.

**Explanation:** You don't get to decide in what language the code that solves the exact problem you have right now is written. The same way you don't get to decide where you get the flat tire. The day will come when you already know C++ and need MATLAB to call into some C++ code (either your code or someone else's). That day you will need to learn how to write a mex file in C++ and compile it for your platform and invoke your code. Or the day will come when you need to invoke Java, and then you will learn how to call into Java.

Obsessing over this when you don't know what you need to do and you're clearly not technically equipped to do it is just a waste of time.

Comment: This answer over and over! focus on writing the best MatLab code you can, and if you get good enough at it, you will delay the day when you have to call other languages from it.

Comment: Actually I mentioned very clearly the specific problem I am presently working at: I would like to access some functions which are provided by the libraries ITK and OpenCV, but not by the MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox. As I am free to learn whatever might be needed to do so, but would like to do it in an effective way, which interface do you recommended to use?

Comment: @Talby: I would use MATITK and mexopencv or the experimental MATLAB module in opencv.

Comment: @carlosdc: Thanks! This gave me direction. I found that MATITIK appers to mainly have evolved due to the work of one student, and his great work seems to not become updated. For openCV I found that it is even featured on THE MATHWORKS site, although somehow hidden. Also, the OpenCV team seems to have released an official set of Matlab bindings. The advice I meanwhile received from the MATLAB support team states that the use of C/C++ MEX-file is recommended if heading for performance (and that´s what the openCV MATLAB binding does) while usage of the JAVA interface would be easier to learn.